# Ansible synchronize module delegate_to could not resolve hostname

Tags: ansible

I am using synchronize module to transfer file form serverA to server B. My serverA and serverB hosts are:

```
[serverB]
172.20.13.201    ansible_user=root   ansible_ssh_pass="hi12#$"
172.20.13.202    ansible_user=root   ansible_ssh_pass="hi12#$"
172.20.13.203    ansible_user=root   ansible_ssh_pass="hi12#$"

[serverA]
172.20.5.121    ansible_user=root   ansible_ssh_pass="hi12#$"
```

my ansible playbook is

```
- hosts: serverB
  tasks:
   - name: Copy Remote-To-Remote
     remote_user: root
     synchronize: src=/root/connection dest=/root/neutron-server.log
     delegate_to: serverA
```

But it error

```
TASK [Copy Remote-To-Remote] ***************************************************
fatal: [172.20.13.201]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: Could not resolve hostname servera: nodename nor servname provided, or not known", "unreachable": true}
fatal: [172.20.13.202]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: Could not resolve hostname servera: nodename nor servname provided, or not known", "unreachable": true}
fatal: [172.20.13.203]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: Could not resolve hostname servera: nodename nor servname provided, or not known", "unreachable": true}
```

Why synchronize can't resolve hostname '**servera**'? In my host file, it's **serverA**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`serverA` is the name of the group. There is no such host. (There might be more hosts in the group `serverA`. It would be difficult to decide which host delegate to.)

Try delegate to 172.20.5.121

```
- hosts: serverB
  tasks:
   - name: Copy Remote-To-Remote
     remote_user: root
     synchronize: src=/root/connection dest=/root/neutron-server.log
     delegate_to: 172.20.5.121
```